# Word for mixing a dish with a fork or spoon

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that can serve in the following context:

> After the pasta  is cooked, put some sauce on top of it and use a spoon to *mix* it together.

Mix seems to be too general, I am looking for something that is related to mixing with the use of a spoon or fork.

Comment: Swirl?  This question might be served up better at the [Cooking SE](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/?as=1). Maybe migrate?

Comment: @J.R.- Maybe. I leave it up to you;)

Comment: My first thought was `blend`, but on second thought that could end badly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The transitive "to stir in" might suit in this context ("...use a spoon to stir it in."). Cookery is broad enough a subject that it has a vocabulary all its own for doing things to other things though, so there might be a specific phrase for mixing sauce into things...

Comment: *Mixing* tends to make me think of using a mixer, not a spoon. As @user653 said, *stir* is probably the best verb in this case.

Comment: Or *blend* as in "blend with a spoon until pasta is coated with sauce."

Comment: @KitFox: "blend" is good if you use it how you suggest, but you have to be careful that the reader doesn't get the idea that they should use their blender! ;)

Answer (score 3):

*Toss* is often used in cooking contexts to indicated the mixing of separate ingredients in a pasta or salad context, though if you are simply stirring, toss could imply too active a combining.  For that matter, *combine* could work as a more generic option, or *stir to combine.*